# Powershell wildcard / regex replace

Tags: regex, powershell, nuget

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to update my `.nuspec` file (nuget depdency) to the latest build version.  I am having trouble with the wildcards though.

So I want to replace the version number of this line

```
<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="1.0.0.0" />
```

to a new version number, i.e. version 2.2.2.2

```
<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="2.2.2.2" />
```

My current place method looks like this.  Note I need a wildcard as I have multiple nuget packages in the solution I need to replace, all follow the format of `MyCompany.PackageName`

```
$filecontent -replace 'id="MyCompany.*" version="*"', "$Version" | Out-File $file
```

But this actually ends up creating

```
<dependency 2.2.2.21.0.0.0" />
```

How do I modify my regex to ensure it replaces the version number component only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with

```
$filecontent -replace 'id="MyCompany(.*?)" version=".*?"', "id=`"MyCompany`$1`" version=`"$Version`"" | Out-File $file
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, if I use double quotes in the second parameter the backslashes don't seem to escape them. But if I use single quotes it writes "$Version" instead of "x.x.x.x"

Comment: @Chris try to escape the `$` just to test

Comment: Ok Ive just realised this doesnt quite work... Now it output `id="MyCompany" version="x.x.x.x"` so it doesnt add the `.Common` back onto `MyCompany`

Comment: @Chris you kept the $1 ?

Comment: capture group replacement only works within 'single quotes'

Comment: Yes its identical bar the backticks...`'id="MyCompany(.*?)" version=".*?"', "id=`"MyCompany$1`" version=`"$Version`""`

Comment: because the shell expands the `$1` if its in double quotes

Comment: @WillBarnwell That seems to be correct, if I swap the `"` for `'` the $1 works but it then writes out `$Version` as a literal rather than "x.x.x.x"

Comment: use `"` and put a ` as a prefix of $1 ? @Chris

Answer (score 2):

I went with a simple use of a capture group so I don't lose the specificity of your regex, matches only strings with 'MyCompany.*' in id, but doesnt add a lot of complexity. I capture everything up to the opening quote in version and replace whatever is before the next quote with the new version number.

```
$test='<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="1.0.0.0" />'
$newVersion='2.2.2.2'
$test -replace "(id=`"MyCompany`..*`" version=)`"[^`"]*","`$1`"$newVersion"

<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="2.2.2.2" />
```

Tested in PS `4.0`

Powershell oddities and fragile bits include:

- backtick to escape instead of `\`
- regex must be in "double quotes"
- must either use single quotes or escapes to have capture groups work in the replacement string

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me Will ;/

Comment: May want to try again, without the `PS >`

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = '<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="2.2.2.2" />'
$s -replace 'version=".*"', 'version="1.2.3.4"'<dependency id="MyCompany.Common" version="1.2.3.4" />
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this is that it may not be `.Common` it might be `.Data` etc so that has to be a wildcard

Comment: @Chris this answer ignores the `id` field completely, it will always persist through with the caveat of also changing the versions on strings that dont have an `id="MyCompany.*"`